# Cannot find symbol on a printf line

Tags: java

Did a little bit of research on this error and most seem simple. I checked to see if i had some spelling errors and I didnt notice any. Im trying to print a few lines using printf. When i go to compile this code it gives me a "cannot find symbol error". Could it be that the method these lines are in need to be in the method the variables are defined? The error is only being done in my printSales method.This isnt the finished product so i may be short a piece or two. But here is my code any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sales
{

    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a product number.");
    double product1 = 0;
    double product2 = 0;
    double product3 = 0;
    double product4 = 0;
    double product5 = 0;
    double sale;

    int userInput = input.nextInt();
        while(userInput != 0)
        {   
           if(userInput >= 1 && userInput <= 5)
           {
            switch(userInput)
            {
                case 1:  System.out.println("");
                        product1 ++;
                        sale += 2.98;
                         break;

            System.out.print("How many were sold?");             
            userInput = input.nextInt();

                case 2:  System.out.println("");
                        product2 ++;
                        sale += 4.50;
                         break;

            System.out.print("How many were sold?");
            userInput = input.nextInt();

                case 3: System.out.println("");
                        product3 ++;
                        sale += 9.98;
                         break;

            System.out.print("How many were sold?");
            userInput = input.nextInt();

                case 4: System.out.println("");
                        product4 ++;
                        sale += 4.49;
                         break;

            System.out.print("How many were sold?");
            userInput = input.nextInt();

                case 5:System.out.println("");
                        product5 ++;
                        sale += 6.87;
                         break;
            System.out.print("How many were sold?");
            userInput = input.nextInt();

            }//end switch
            } //end if
        else if (userInput != 0)
            bSystem.out.println("ERROR: Incorrect Product Number, Please Try Again");
            System.out.print("");
            userInput = input.nextInt();
        }//end while 
    } //end main
    public void printSales()
    {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Product 1: $%.2f\n", product1);
    System.out.printf("Product 2: $%.2f\n", product2);
    System.out.printf("Product 3: $%.2f\n", product3);
    System.out.printf("Product 4: $%.2f\n", product4);
    System.out.printf("Product 5: $%.2f\n", product5);
    } //end printSales
} //end class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the scope of your variables. You cannot refer to variables from one method in another method. Try redefining printSales:

```
public void printSales(int product1, int product2, int product3, int product4, int product5)
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Product 1: $%.2f\n", product1);
    System.out.printf("Product 2: $%.2f\n", product2);
    System.out.printf("Product 3: $%.2f\n", product3);
    System.out.printf("Product 4: $%.2f\n", product4);
    System.out.printf("Product 5: $%.2f\n", product5);
} //end printSales
```

and then of course you will have to change how you call printSales (which I see you are not calling now, but perhaps you will call it in the future):

```
printSales(product1, product2, product3, product4, product5);
```

Be sure that product1, product2, etc are all in the same "scope"-- you can't reach into another method, or into an if{} or for{} or while{} block to reference variables.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to java but that means the print statements need to be in the main method with the variables or is there a way to call from one method to another?

Comment: Exactly. You can either put them in the main method, or you can change the printSales method like I did above and then put the printSales(product1.....) line in your main method. That would allow you to run printSales from in your main method.

Answer (score 1):

Four problems...

## 1

`sale might not be initialised`...

You declare the `sale` variable as...

```
double sale;
```

As a local variable, it has no default value, so doing something like `sale += 2.98` has undefined results.

Simple initialize the variable to a default/starting value...

```
double sale = 0d;
```

## 2

> package bSystem does not exist
> bSystem.out.println("ERROR: Incorrect Product Number, Please Try Again");

Typo, it should be `System.out.println` ;)

## 3

> error: cannot find symbol
>           System.out.printf("Product 1: $%.2f\n", product1);

The values `product1`, `product2`, `product3`, `product4` and `product5` have no meaning in `printSales` as they've only been declared as local variables within `main`.

Normally, I would suggest making these instance variables, but because you're running within a `static` context of `main`, this won't work.  Instead, modify the `printSales` method to take parameters...

```
public void printSales(double product1, double product2, double product3, double product4, double product5) {
    ...
}
```

## 4

You should be getting a number of warnings about 'unreachable statement`, this caused by the fact that you`break`out of the`switch` statement, but attempt to execute code after it...

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("");
    product1++;
    sale += 2.98;
    break;

    System.out.print("How many were sold?");
    userInput = input.nextInt();
    ^--- These can't be executed, because of the break before it...
```

Instead, try moving the code before the `break` statement....

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("");
    product1++;
    sale += 2.98;

    System.out.print("How many were sold?");
    userInput = input.nextInt();
    break;
```

You might like to take a look at [the Variables trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) and [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for some more details

Comment: Thank you so much. I didnt even notice that typo. I appreciate it so much.

Comment: Good answer, but 1) is wrong. Java automatically initialized all variables. Numeric ones are 0 by default.

Comment: @Felk Only instance variables are initialised, unless it's changed in Java 8, local variables are undefined by the lanugage specification

Comment: @MagProgrammer Right, I got confused. While it is correct, that java does not have uninitialized variables, local variables need to be initialized or cause a compile error

Comment: @Felk "uninitialized" might be the wrong word, but I took the "warning" message directly, "undefined" might be more accurate...

Comment: @Felk Does that mean I'm going to get the downvote reversed ;)

Comment: ah, sure, forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

The variables "double product1/2/3..." are *local* variables, i.e. their scope and life-cycle are restricted inside the main method - you cannot reach them from printSales().

To solve the problem and be able to modify/call the variables, make them as fields instead. That is, place them inside the context of the *class* and not a *method*.

```
public class Sales
{    
//variables moved into the context of the class, i.e. you can reach them from
//all methods of this class. Furhermore, they have to be static in order to be
//accessed from a static method.
private static double product1 = 0;
private static double product2 = 0;
private static double product3 = 0;
private static double product4 = 0;
private static double product5 = 0;
private static double sale;

public static void main( String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a product number.");
    //rest of main method but without vairables
}
```